# phpmyadmin BUG:A comma or a closing bracket was expected

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

My PHPMyAdmin always warn me

> A comma or a closing bracket was expected

when I try to use a function.

Although it displays warnings, the SQL statements can be successfully executed.

For example ,here's a piece of SQL code

```
    INSERT INTO payments (`amount`,`alloted`, `dateadded`, `modified`, `userid`)
    VALUES ( 100, DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH),NOW(),NOW(),139107 )
```

[image]

When typing the function 'NOW()', the red underline comes up, it's really, REAAALYYY annoying

Same errors come up when typing all kinds of sql functions

[image]

I've tried re-installing phpmyadmin but it doesn't work at all.
This bug only occurs when I'm using ubuntu on my web server,
the warning messages never comes up when I debuggling on localhost.

here's the common error message.

```
Error

Static analysis:

4 errors were found during analysis.

A comma or a closing bracket was expected (near "(" at position 40)
Unexpected token. (near "'123'" at position 41)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 46)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 47)

SQL query:

INSERT INTO accounts(pw) VALUES(PASSWORD('123'))
```

Comment: Why not use [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)? I've always found phpMyAdmin to be a pale imitation of that. Is it possible this is settings related?

Comment: I just completely don't know why it occurs. I believe there must be a way to fix it, but I just don't know how.

Comment: That syntax validation seems overly paranoid. Are you sure you haven't toggled some kind of setting?

Comment: I don't think so, I've just re-installed it and the warning still comes up. In fact there's nothing wrong with the statements

Comment: Note that using MySQL's `PASSWORD` function for hashing passwords is a pretty bad idea. At the absolute least use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it is not a question. Bug reports for software products should be directed to the product vendor.

Answer (score 0):

- What version of PHPMyAdmin are you running?
- And with what version of MySQL?

You probably need to post this on the [**PHPMyAdmin bugs repository**](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/).

It is not a bug with the SQL processing itself; it is a bug with the new PhpMyAdmin SQL validator javasscript and its inferance of the structure of SQL queries.

SQL can be very complex (part of its attraction) so it's to be expected that there will be cases where the validator gets confused.

---

Also;

> ```
> INSERT INTO accounts(pw) VALUES(PASSWORD('123'))
> ```

Should be:

```
INSERT INTO accounts(`pw`) VALUES(PASSWORD('123'))
```

note the backticks. PHPMyAdmin is extremely pernickerty that column names (and table names) be always backtick quoted.

Comment: thanks a lot ! I'm using ubuntu 16.0.4 so everything was downloaded with apt-get. the mysql version is  `Distrib 5.7.19 Ver 14.14`, and my phpmyadmin ver is `4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2`

Comment: maybe i should update my phpMyAdmin to a newer version, since the latest version is 4.7.3 XD

Comment: Since `pw` isn't a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) that should not be necessary.

Comment: @tadman no but PHPMyAdmin is extremely pernickerty that column names (and table names) be **always** backtick quoted.

Comment: I've tried backtick quote and it doesn't work as well.

Comment: @COSLOLI see the original statement in my answer -- their Javascript for checking SQL doesn't take into account all the options; you should check for an existing bug report in the link provided and if there is none, submit your own.

Answer (score -1):

One cause is: If you have **columns/fields** defined as not **null**, make sure that corresponding  **variables** in sql are **not null or empty** as this would prevent the insert

Comment: This is incorrect. Empty values can be happily inserted. And the issue is about syntax rather than data contents.